# How do i force java methods to run specific implementations

Tags: java

I have 2 overloaded method, one which runs a superclass and one which runs a subclass. i would expect that when sending a subclass, java would know to run the method specific to the subclass. Alas, it runs the one of the superclass. Here is an example:

```
public class Test {

    static class SuperClass {}

    static class SubClass extends SuperClass {}

    static void stuff(SuperClass superclass) {
        System.out.println("IN 1");
    }

    static void stuff(SubClass subClass) {
        System.out.println("IN 2");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SuperClass aClass = new SubClass() ;

        stuff(aClass) ;
    }
}
```

I would expect "IN 2" to be printed but instead i get "IN 1"

so i have 2 questions:
1. Why is it happening
2. How do i achieve my wanted result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Details of how it works: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why is it happening

Because the overload resolution happens at *compile-time*, and the compile-time type of the `aClass` variable is `SuperClass`

> How do i achieve my wanted result?

Either change the compile-time type of `aClass` to `SubClass`:

```
SubClass aClass = new SubClass();
```

Or cast in the method call:

```
stuff((SubClass) aClass);
```

If you want to *actually* be able to handle any `SuperClass`, you should look into *overriding* instead of *overloading*, or the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) / [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch).

Comment: Or a simple `instanceof` may suffice, depending on the situation of course.

Answer (score 2):

By declaring aClass as an instance of SubClass

```
 SuperClass aClass = new SubClass() ;
```

Even though you instantiate it as a SubClass, you declare it as a SuperClass. Change that line to:

```
SubClass aClass = new SubClass() ;
```

and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Like Mr Skeet said, it is happening because the compile-time type of `aClass` variable is `SuperClass`. Here is an example of using an [interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) and `instanceof`

```
public class Legit {

    public static interface Animal {}

    public static abstract class Mammal implements Animal {}

    public static class Lion extends Mammal {}

    public static class Cow extends Mammal {}

    public static abstract class Reptile implements Animal {}

    public static class Snake extends Reptile {}

    public static void doSomething(Animal animal) {
        if (animal instanceof Lion) {
            System.out.println("RAAWWRR!");
        } else if (animal instanceof Cow) {
            System.out.println("MOOO!");
        } else if (animal instanceof Reptile) {
            System.out.println("HISSSSS!");
        }
    }

    public static void main (String ... args) {
        Animal animal1 = new Lion();
        Animal animal2 = new Cow();
        Animal animal3 = new Snake();

        doSomething(animal1);
        doSomething(animal2);
        doSomething(animal3);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
RAAWWRR!
MOOO!
HISSSSS!
```